# How to output the choices of the questions inside a box?

Tags: macros, boxes, questionnaire

I plan to create a command where I can use to output the choices inside the box and above the list of questions but its a know how. This is a sample output of what i am saying. I will use the `\question` command to output the questions. [image: choices are in the box]

Comment: Though the expected output is clear, it is not clear what kind of macro you're looking for. I'd appreciate if you can give us some example code using the non-existent macro... We could then help you write that macro... Thank you.

Comment: using the exam document class would like to write the macro this way: 
##Code
\documentclass{exam}

\begin{document}
 
 \begin{questions}
 \begin{choiceinbox}
 \cb choice1
 \cb choice2
 \cb choice3
 \cb choice4
 \cb choice5
 
 \question text here text here text here text here text here
 \question text here text here text here text here text here
 \question text here text here text here text here text here
 \question text here text here text here text here text here
 \question text here text here text here text here text here
 
 \end{choiceinbox}
 \end{questions}
 
 
 
\end{document}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}

\def\qns#1{\begin{center}\fbox{\parbox{.95\textwidth}{\begin{multicols}{4}%
\renewcommand\theenumi{\alph{enumi})}\begin{enumerate}%
#1%
\end{enumerate}\end{multicols}}}\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\qns{
\item  worda
\item wordb
\item other word
\item wordd
\item plan e
\item alternive f
\item something else
\item obviously wrong
\item \textbf{\textit{choose me}}
\item something else
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: absolutely better :)